# Display/Interact web page embedded in Python3 GUI Application

Tags: python-3.x, html

I'm looking for a way to show a web site inside one of the windows of a Python3 GUI application.  I'm expecting to run this window in a separate thread so the website can be interacted with and update it's own window independently of the rest of the application.  Most the searching I've done so far, only shows how to scrape a website, which is not what I need.
  ghost.show() does show the website, for about a second or so before the window closes; I haven't seen how to keep this open and running for the life of the python3 application.  Is there any way to keep ghost.show() running for an unlimited amount of time?

Are there any other Python libraries that would work?

Environment:  Python3, Ubuntu/Debian Linux

Thanks,

Harlan...

Answer (score 2):

Each UI framework have its own way of doing this:

QT - https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiohJLSuevQAhVFuI8KHfGlCM4QFgg1MAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdoc.qt.io%2Fqt-5%2Ftopics-web-content.html&usg=AFQjCNHnTUydi4WlSjzdD9ZDYG-98h4NOg&sig2=pnAXLPq2hr7hJNYE9fbCOA

WX - https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiVyoP3uevQAhXMr48KHbvxD_4QFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F20005515%2Fimplementing-a-simple-web-browser-with-wxpython&usg=AFQjCNEaZx6eFFHTX_xDVx3HLC50yqugLw&sig2=-zqoatandTZam_dqCZnNzw&bvm=bv.141320020,d.c2I

But I would sugget to just call the *[webbrowser](https://pymotw.com/3/webbrowser/)* module that will open a native web browser on your platform .

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open(
    'https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html'
)
```